# How to order queries of one table based on the sum of a column in a related table

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `users` table with columns

`id`, `username`, `password`

I also have an `orders` table with columns

`id`, `user_id`, `price`, `status`

In the `index` method of the `UsersController`, I would like to order my users based on the amount of purchases they have made. The purchases of each user can be gotten as the sum of the `price` of all the orders in which the `user_id` of the order is equal to the `id` of a user and in which the `order.status` of such an order is equal to `4`

The restriction in order status is made because users have the possibility of cancelling orders in my system so I'll like to query only the orders which have not been canceled.

Basically, I'll like to get the list of all users based on the total amount of purchases they have made. I'll also like to paginate the results

#### Trials

I tried getting the users based on the query below. I'm using `leftJoin` because not all the users have made an order.

```
$users = User::leftJoin('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
     ->where('orders.status', '!=', 2)->where('orders.status', '!=', 5)
     ->groupBy('orders.user_id');
```

But yet I still get errors.

Based on my Models, I could get all the purchases of a particular user by using a query such as

```
 User::find(1)->orders()->where('orders.status', '=', 4)->sum('orders.price')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does Laravel not require full `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... WHERE ... GROUP BY` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials I got a good and simple solution

```
$users = User::leftJoin('orders', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
     ->select('users.*', DB::raw( 'sum( orders.price ) as `total_purchase`' ) )
     ->groupBy('users.id')
     ->orderBy('total_purchase', 'DSC')
     ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure SQL for this will look something like this:

```
SET @rank = 0;

SELECT
   @rank := @rank + 1 AS Rank
  ,Username
FROM (
  SELECT
    U.username AS Username
  FROM orders O
  JOIN users U
    ON U.id = O.user_id
  WHERE O.status = 4
  GROUP BY
    O.user_id
  ORDER BY
    SUM(O.price) DESC
) X;

-- Reset Rank
SET @rank = 0;
```

Comment: Would I  be able to paginate this?

Comment: Currently, that's raw output... Your pagination depends on the PHP implementation. You could add row numbers and nest it as a sub-`SELECT` in a `SELECT` that pulls row numbers X thru Y based on your required pagination...

Answer (score 0):

```
 ->groupBy('orders.user_id')
```

You should group by `users.id` instead because `orders.user_id` will be null if a user has not placed an order.

Comment: I would also like to sort the results based on the  purchase amount